# Xcode downloaded device app container gives empty Core Data .sqlite

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, core-data

When I try to view the Core Data objects from my app - by downloading the App Container and going to `/AppData/Library/ApplicationSupport` - the MyApp.sqlite file is empty. If I open it in any SQLite database browser it shows the indexes but no objects.

The objects show up when I use Core Data inside the app, and there are many objects in the .sqlite file - but when I download it and try to view outside the app, the .sqlite is empty.

[image: Downloading the app container]

Downloading the app container

[image: App Container SQLite location]

Navigating to the .sqlite file

[image: Empty .sqlite]

Empty .sqlite - only contains indexes and no objects

Comment: Does sqlite viewer support the -wal journal mode of sqlite?  iOS uses wal mode by default, so the data is in the -wal file, not the sqlite file.  You will need a sqlite browser that supports accessing that file.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest copy all the 3 files (.sqlite, .sqlite-shm, .sqlite-wal) to your folder and open sqlite file by using DB Browser (for sqlite) or some other tool, you will get all the data for sure while browsing the table.